# Geographic coordinates to cartesian point on sphere

Tags: math, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

I’m trying to calculate location on sphere in cartesian from geographic coordinates. I made blueprint to do this but it doesn’t work.
It is using this formula:

```
x = R * cos(lat) * cos(lon)
y = R * cos(lon) * sin(lat)
z = R *sin(lat)
```

My blueprint:
[image: My Blueprint]
In my scene I’ve created a sphere with country borders texture. In blueprint I set Coords to US geographic coordinates but Debug Point is drawn in wrong place.

Comment: I have no idea about Unreal but one of the most common cause of such problems as you report is confusion over degrees and radians in measuring angles. The picture (which uses terms such as `COSd`) is at odds with the formulae you show.

Comment: As @HighPerformanceMark said, the nodes `SINd` and `COSd` are specific for degrees. Try using `SIN` and `COS` instead. [See docs](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.1/en-US/BlueprintAPI/Math/Trig/)

Comment: Given that Lat/Lon *are* degree values, the ```SINd``` and ```COSd``` are likely correct.  The issue you're probably having is +/- on latitude, which can be fixed by adding 90 to your Latitude and adapting your math from there.  For better help, please share an image showing the plot output and where you expected it to be.